# Appending a dataframe with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I'm iterating through csv files that is one by one loaded into a dataframe. Here I have a dataframe; df, and a temp df; df_tmp, where I load a file to df_tmp and then append the df with the content from df_tmp.

Doing like this;

```
df = pd.concat([df_tmp, df], axis=0, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

But I would like to change it, so I add an extra index, that could be something unique - like the filename.

how to append a dataframe with multiindex?

```
      0   1
A 0   1   2
  1   3   4
B 0   5   6
  1   7   8
C 0   9  10
  1  11  12
```

appended with;

```
      0   1
D d   3   11
  e   6   8
```

so the result is;

```
      0   1
A 0   1   2
  1   3   4
B 0   5   6
  1   7   8
C 0   9  10
  1  11  12
D d   3   11
  e   6   8
```

Comment: simple pd.concat([df,df2]) works for me.. ?

Comment: Is the first index (A,B,C,D) already present, or is that the index you want to add as identifier?